# Prove that the upper integral $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx$ is equal to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-sum

Let $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if }x=0\\
0&\text{ if }x\neq 0.\end{cases}$

Prove that the upper integral $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx$  is equal to $0$.

Here is my attempt:

fix $\epsilon > 0$. If we compute the upper Darboux sum using the division $D=\{-1,-\frac{\epsilon}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2},1\}$ we get:

$S(D) = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \delta_i F_i$ where $F_i = sup\{f(x): x_{i-1} < x < x_i\}$

$\sum_{i=1}^{3} \delta_i F_i = (-\frac{\epsilon}{2} - (-1))F_1 + (\frac{\epsilon}{2} - (-\frac{\epsilon}{2}))F_2 + (1 -\frac{\epsilon}{2})F_3 $

since $ 0 \notin[-1, -\frac{\epsilon}{2}]$ and $ 0 \notin[\frac{\epsilon}{2}, 1], F_1 = F_3= 0$. Since $0 \in[-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \frac{\epsilon}{2}]$, then $F_2 = 1$.

Then we have that:$(-\frac{\epsilon}{2} - (-1))F_1 + (\frac{\epsilon}{2} - (-\frac{\epsilon}{2}))F_2 + (1 -\frac{\epsilon}{2})F_3 = (1-\frac{\epsilon}{2})(0) + (2\frac{\epsilon}{2})(1) + (1-\frac{\epsilon}{2})(0) = 0 + \epsilon$.

It follows that $\forall_{\epsilon>0}$ there exists a division such that $0 < S(D) < \epsilon$. Also $f(x) \geq 0$ so $S(D) \geq 0$ for any division. Therefore, from the definition of the infimum $inf\{S(D): D \text{ is a division of  }[-1,1]\} = 0 = \text{ upper}\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx$

is this proof OK?

Comment: The general idea is correct although the notation and presentation is a bit sloppy.

Comment: That's a complicated way to say something simple.

Comment: How can I simplify it? Is it better to say that as $\epsilon$ approaches zero, the lower darboux sum approaches zero and therefore the upper integral is zero?

Comment: The lower sum is unrelated to the upper sum and upper integral. Anything you say about the lower sum means nothing about the upper sum and upper integral.

Comment: Can I say that as as ϵ approaches zero, the upper darboux sum approaches zero and therefore the upper integral is zero?

Comment: No — you can only say that the infimum of the upper sums amongst the particular sets $D$ you construct using values of $\epsilon$ approaches zero. There may be other partitions for which the infimum of the upper sum is negative, and you can't rule this out until you conclude that all partitions have a non-negative upper sum using the fact that the infimum of the function itself is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

> It follows that $\forall_{\epsilon>0}$ there exists a division such that $0 < S(D) < \epsilon$. Also $f(x) \geq 0$ so $S(D) \geq 0$ for any division. Therefore, from the definition of the infimum $inf\{S(D): D \text{ is a division of  }[-1,1]\} = 0 = \text{ upper}\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx$

I would write:

> Thus, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a division $D$ such that $S(D) = \epsilon$. This implies that
>
> $$\mathrm{inf} \big\{ S(D) \;\big|\; D \text{ is a partition of } [-1, 1] \big\} \leq \epsilon.$$
>
> In the limit as $\epsilon$ tends to zero, we thus have
>
> $$\mathrm{inf} \big\{ S(D) \;\big|\; D \text{ is a partition of } [-1, 1] \big\} \leq 0.$$
>
> Since $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$, we have $S(D) \geq 0$ for any choice of division $D$. This means that
>
> $$\mathrm{inf} \big\{ S(D) \;\big|\; D \text{ is a partition of } [-1, 1] \big\} \geq 0.$$
>
> Collectively, this means the infimum is equal to zero, and so by definition of the upper integral, that is also equal to zero.